# How to scanf into dynamically allocated struct int

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct { 
    char* name;
    int* phone;
} person;
```

Allocated like this:

```
person* Person[numNames];
    for (i =0; i<numNames; i++) { 
        Person[i] = malloc(sizeof(person));
        Person[i]->name = malloc(25 * sizeof(char));
        Person[i]->phone = malloc(sizeof(int));
        memset(Person[i]->phone, 0, sizeof(int));
    }
```

Reading input into phone like this:

```
  for (i=0; i<numNames; i++) {
    printf("%s: ", Person[i]->name);
    scanf("%d", &Person[i]->phone);
  }
```

This gives me a segmentation fault: (Also freeing Person[i]->phone gives me segmentation fault)

```
 for (i =0; i<numNames; i++) { 
    printf("%s: %d", Person[i]->name, *Person[i]->phone);
  }
```

How can I properly scanf into Person[i]->phone without a segmentation fault?

Comment: Why allocate memory for a single `int`? And suppose the phone number contains non-digits, such as `'+'`?

Comment: Remove & in scanf. It should be scanf("%d", Person[i]->phone);

Comment: Note: Phone numbers consist of single digits and special symbols. Both are single characters, symbols are not integers and digits can be adjascent. So any reason to use an `int` array and not a simple `char` array?

Comment: @Olaf worse yet it was an `int` array of length `1`.

Comment: @sdfsdfsdf how do you propose to encode a telephone number with a leading `0`, or two leading `0`s?

Comment: That your compiler didn't warn you about the mismatched `scanf` arguments (something to the effect of "Format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int **'") is concerning. Every modern compiler I know of does so now. Turn up your warnings to pedantic levels.

Comment: Ahh, I oversaw that one. I start wondering what has become of the general (not just programming-related) practice: "think first, then act"?

Answer (score 0):

[`scanf` requires you to pass a pointer to the "target" memory locations.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)You're currently taking a pointer to a pointer here:

```
scanf("%d", &Person[i]->phone);
```

...but `Person[i]->phone` is already a `int*`, pointing to a memory location suitable for one `int`. The following call will correctly fill the `phone` field.

```
scanf("%d", Person[i]->phone);
```